# dynamicaly add dropdown field in jquery in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

This is my jquery code where I want add dynamic fields like:

input,
select,
file,
textarea 
etc.

I want to add dynamic fields with validation and insert those into the database like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var count = 0;
            $(function(){

            $('#add_field').click(function(){

            count += 1;
            $('#container').append('<strong>Product Name</strong>'+'<input id="product_name' + count + '" name="product_name[]' + '" type="text" />'+ 
                                   '<strong>Product Image</strong>'+'<input id="user_file' + count + '" name="user_file[]' + '" type="file" />'+
                                   '<strong>Product Category</strong>'+'<?php echo form_dropdown('cat', $cat); ?>'+
                                   '<strong>Product Description</strong>'+'<input id="product_description' + count + '" name="product_description[]' + '" type="textarea" />'
                                  );
        });
    });
        </script>
```

in debugger show this output

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var count = 0;
        $(function(){

        $('#add_field').click(function(){

        count += 1;
        $('#container').append('<strong>Product Name</strong>'+'<input id="product_name' + count + '" name="product_name[]' + '" type="text" />'+ 
                               '<strong>Product Image</strong>'+'<input id="user_file' + count + '" name="user_file[]' + '" type="file" />'+
                               '<strong>Product Category</strong>'+'<select name="cat">
<option value="0">Select Category</option>
<option value="1"> Industrial Plant & Machinary</option>
<option value="2">Electronics & Electrical </option>
<option value="3">Industrial Supplies</option>
<option value="4"> Food & Beverages</option>
<option value="5"> Building & Construction</option>
<option value="6">Apparel & Garments</option>
<option value="7"> Chemicals, Dyes & Solvents</option>
<option value="8"> Medical & Healthcare</option>
<option value="9">Packaging Machines & Goods </option>
<option value="10"> Mechanical Parts & Spares</option>
<option value="11"> Housewares & Supplies</option>
<option value="12">Lab Instruments & Supplies </option>
<option value="13"> Handicrafts & Decoratives</option>
<option value="14">Automobile, Parts & Spares</option>
<option value="15"> Furniture & Supplies</option>
<option value="16"> Hand & Machine Tools</option>
<option value="17"> Textiles, Yarn & Fabrics</option>
<option value="18">Cosmetics & Personal Care</option>
<option value="19"> Metals, Alloys & Minerals</option>
<option value="20">Fashion Accessories & Gear</option>
<option value="21"> Gems, Jewelry & Astrology</option>
<option value="22"> Home Textile & Furnishing</option>
<option value="23"> Agriculture & Farming</option>
<option value="24"> Bags, Belts & Wallets</option>
<option value="25"> Engineering Services</option>
<option value="26"> Herbal & Ayurvedic Product</option>
<option value="27">Sports Goods, Toys & Games</option>
<option value="28"> Computer & IT Solutions</option>
<option value="29"> Kitchen Utensils & Appliances</option>
<option value="30"> Paper & Paper Products</option>
<option value="31"> Media, PR & Publishing</option>
<option value="32">Business & Audit Services</option>
<option value="33"> Books & Stationery</option>
<option value="34">Telecom Equipment & Goods</option>
<option value="35">Transportation & Logistics</option>
<option value="36">IT & Telecom Services</option>
<option value="37">Education & Training</option>
<option value="38"> Marble, Granite & Stones</option>
<option value="39"> Call Center & BPO Services</option>
<option value="40"> Travel, Tourism & Hotels</option>
<option value="41">Bicycle, Rickshaw & Spares</option>
<option value="42"> Financial & Legal Service</option>
<option value="43"> Leather Products</option>
<option value="44">Product Rental & Leasing</option>
<option value="45"> HR Planning & Recruitment</option>
<option value="46"> Architecture & Interiors</option>
<option value="47">Event Planner & Organizer</option>
<option value="48">R&D and Testing Labs</option>
<option value="49"> Facility Management</option>
<option value="50"> Contractors & Freelancers</option>
<option value="51">Rail, Shipping & Aviation</option>
<option value="52"> Security System CCTV</option>
<option value="53"> Web design & development</option>
<option value="54">Industrial Products</option>
<option value="55">Interior & Furnishings</option>
<option value="56"> Hardware & Paints</option>
<option value="57"> Incense, Agarbatti & Pooja Material</option>
<option value="58"> Centering Plates</option>
<option value="59"> Adjustable Spans</option>
<option value="60">ADJUSTABLE STEEL PROPS ADJUSTABLE STEEL PROPS</option>
<option value="61"> FLOOR FORM SINGLE SHEET BEND</option>
<option value="62"> H FRAME</option>
<option value="63">AUTOMOBILE JACKS</option>
<option value="64"> CUP LOCK SYSTEMS</option>
<option value="65">FORM WORK</option>
<option value="66"> ROUND COLUMN</option>
<option value="67"> UNIVERSAL STIRUP HEAD AND BASE JACK</option>
<option value="68"> WALL FORM STANDARD</option>
<option value="69"> TRUSELL</option>
<option value="70"> Cement Products</option>
<option value="71">Fabrication</option>
<option value="72"> Safety Products </option>
<option value="73">Machines and Equipments</option>
<option value="74"> Gloves</option>
<option value="75"> Packaging Material</option>
<option value="76">Photostat Machines</option>
<option value="77">Binding Machines</option>
<option value="78"> Voltage Stabilizer</option>
<option value="79"> Multifunction Printer Machines</option>
<option value="80"> Scanner Machine</option>
<option value="81">Lamination Machine</option>
<option value="82">Color Printers</option>
<option value="83"> Toner cartridge</option>
<option value="84"> Photostat Machine Spare Parts</option>
<option value="85"> Photostat Machines Repairing Service</option>
<option value="86"> Photostat Machine Maintenance Service</option>
<option value="87">Art</option>
<option value="88">Industrial Valves</option>
<option value="89"> Industrial Fittings </option>
<option value="90"> Pressure Gavge</option>
<option value="91"> Bkl-product</option>
</select>
'+
                               '<strong>Product Description</strong>'+'<input id="product_description' + count + '" name="product_description[]' + '" type="textarea" />'
                              );
    });
});
    </script>
```

but why do i get in the console this error?

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

Comment: why are you concating in name attribute? `name="product_name[]' + '`
just put `name="product_name[]"`

Comment: for this -> `<?php echo form_dropdown('cat', $cat); ?>` it might be consider cat as a js variable change it like this `<?php echo form_dropdown("cat", $cat); ?>`

Comment: Put `<?php echo form_dropdown('cat', $cat); ?>` it in any php variable then encode it in js varable then pass that variable in `append`

Answer (score 0):

Sometime php,html creates an issue in javascript, Put  it in any php variable then encode it in js variable then pass that variable in append, like this

```
 $('#add_field').click(function(){
        <php $dropdown = <?php echo form_dropdown('cat', $cat); ?>; ?>

        var dropdown = <?php echo json_encode($dropdown); ?>;
        count += 1;
        $('#container').append('<strong>Product Name</strong>'+'<input id="product_name' + count + '" name="product_name[]' + '" type="text" />'+ 
                               '<strong>Product Image</strong>'+'<input id="user_file' + count + '" name="user_file[]' + '" type="file" />'+
                               '<strong>Product Category</strong>'+ dropdown +
                               '<strong>Product Description</strong>'+'<input id="product_description' + count + '" name="product_description[]' + '" type="textarea" />'
                              );
    });
```

hope it helps.